# Windows Phone 7 Web Browser Navigating to an html file located in a folder within the solution

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

Uri currURI = new Uri(currentPageToLoad, UriKind.Relative);
ExtrasHTMLbrowser.Navigate(currURI);

The above code basically is grabbing a string (currentPageToLoad) and making a URI. Then my web browser, ExtrasHTMLbrowser, is trying to navigate to the URI. When currentPageToLoad is something like "author.html" it works perfectly, and navigates to the html page.

However, the problem I am having is that when the html file is in a folder such as HTML, it won't navigate properly. So, when currentPageToLoad = "HTML/author.html" the phone will give me the generic 404 not found page.

Any Idea why it would matter if the file was in a folder, or am I trying to access the file incorrectly?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!
-Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `HTML` file to build type `Content`.Then do this:

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("HTML/author.html", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
```

This will read the entire HTML file as a string. You can then use the WebBrowser control's `NavigateToString` method like this:

```
ExtrasHTMLbrowser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

If you have images/CSS you want to use, then you'll have to use the above method to read the HTML file as a string and save it into Isolated Storage, alongside the images and CSS files (with matching directories).

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would go about saving them to isolated storage, right now as im trying to do that I am having errors.

Comment: There's an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28v=VS.92%29.aspx. If you're still getting errors, it's best to create a new question (with your Isolated Storage code and error messages)

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to navigate between multiple pages you'll first need to copy the files to IsolatedStorage. It's not possible to navigate between pages if you navigate to a file directly within the XAP. (The relative paths are unusable and you can't access such files via an absolute Uri.)